# Java - Get string path of resource files

Tags: java, url, jar, resources, path

I want to access to get the string path to my resource key files. If I debug the project in eclipse, everything works like a charm but if I export the project to a runnable .jar file - the project can't access the key files because the path is wrong.

```
PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = "src/resources/public.key";
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "src/resources/private.key";
```

But how do I get the right path for the runnable .jar file? I don't want to get the URL or anything else - I want to get the string path.

I hope that someone can help me.

---

**Solution:**

```
public static String PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = "/resources/public.key";
public static String PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "/resources/private.key";
```

I'm using an `InputStream` to read the file content:

```
InputStream in = ExampleClass.class.getResourceAsStream(PUBLIC_KEY_PATH);
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedReader(in));
```

There we go ;)

Comment: Just a hint, I don't think the path to the resources will be "src/resources/", it will be more like "/resources/". I'm not familiar with Eclipse's Jar'ing process, but I'm pretty sure "src" will equate to the root level of the Jar...

Comment: For the .jar file that doesnt work. But if I just compile it in eclipse that works. I need a way which works for both.

Comment: I'd suggest that you need to change the execution context for Eclipse. I don't use Eclipse personally, but Netbeans does this type of thing just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an [`inputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) from the file via [`Class#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). For example:

```
InputStream is = FooClass.class.getResourceAsStream("public.key");
```

where you save `public.key` file in the same directory <strike>`FooClass.java`</strike> `FooClass.class` is located in.

Comment: I'd use `FooClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/public.key");` (note the slash before the file name).

Answer (score 0):

YOu can copy those keys into `WEB-INF/classes` and where ever you are loading those, call

`this.getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`.